# SQL Update Trigger - keep all sessions/versions

Tags: sql-server

I have a production table called InvStockTake (P) and this table replicates to another server to a table also called InvStockTake(R).
Will reference them P for production and R for replication.

On the Replication table InvStockTake(R) I created an insert trigger, as below, which will copy the inserted data to another table called InvStockTakeReplicate(R)

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[InvStockTake] 
FOR INSERT
AS  
    insert into SysproCompanyR.dbo.InvStockTakeReplicate
           (Warehouse,StockCode,Bin,OrigQtyOnHand,QtyCaptured,SaveDate,ProductClass,Uom,Reference,PrintedFlag,Decimals,NumTimesCaptured,CreatedBinFlag,SelectionCost) 
    SELECT  Warehouse,StockCode,Bin,OrigQtyOnHand,QtyCaptured,SaveDate,ProductClass,Uom,Reference,PrintedFlag,Decimals,NumTimesCaptured,CreatedBinFlag,SelectionCost 

    FROM inserted;
```

The problem is, the table in my production table, will let's say look like this

```
Warehouse   StockCode   Bin OrigQtyOnHand   QtyCaptured SaveDate    ProductClass NumTimesCaptured
A1          20402205   S10D04       12       12         2016-10-27           333  3
A1          20402206   S10D03       11       11         2016-10-27           376  2
A1          30303021   S10F04        2       2          2016-10-27           354  1
A1          32700103   S10A04        1       1          2016-10-27           333  1
```

and when it gets inserted this will replicate to my other table.
Now how this table works is people will continuously capture in here while a warehouse is in stock take mode. So you will see the numtimescapture column will update as numerous people capture, also qtycaptured can change.

So I will need an update trigger as well, but now say the stock take is finished, and 2 weeks later this warehouse A1 is placed into stock take mode, it will wipe all A1 stock takes from my production database and insert new records of the stock they need to count again. But now the save date will change to a new date.
Now I assume when this happens, since I only have an insert trigger it will just insert these new records. But what will happen with my update trigger? It will need to update the record with the new date....

So if someone can assist me with this update trigger, it will help immensely, since I need to build a table in the end that will keep all different stock take sessions/versions.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an audit trail/history of changes?

Comment: No, the reason i need to do this, the system wipes the data in the production INVSTOCKTAKE table, and i want to keep history of when stock take's took place, and how much was counted. To keep record

Comment: So yes. It's an audit trail/history of changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to keep every version of every record, your UPDATE trigger can be the same as your INSERT trigger. All you have to do is change it from:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[InvStockTake] 
FOR INSERT
AS
```

To:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[InvStockTake] 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks ben ill have a check :) One thing ofcourse which I did mention is, I use transactional replication to replicate my production table with a replicated db with the same table, only because I don't want to write triggers etc on a production server. But for some reason it doesn't see replicated data as insert data....but if I manually insert a row yes then it works...any idea?

Comment: Replicate the history table as well.

Comment: Also  my InvStockTake table have a primary key made up of 3 columns. How will I do the update statement(fortrigger) since my table will have duplicates in...only my save date will determine the difference as well is my identity key I made for my replicate/history table.

Comment: The only columns from my inserted values that will be updated or changed for that specific row will always only be column (qtycaptured) and (numtimecaptured) so I need an update trigger that will update that specific row for those 2 columns for that unique row

Comment: You can choose which columns you put into the history table, just write the appropriate insert/select from statement. You will want the primary key fields, plus any other fields of interest. For simplicity I suggest you just take all fields. Maybe only those fields change today but tomorrow other fields may change.